# Question from IOQM 2021 based on functions

Tags: functions, polynomials

Suppose that $P$ is the polynomial of least degree with integer coefficients such that
$$P(\sqrt{7} + \sqrt{5}) = 2(\sqrt{7} - \sqrt{5}).$$
Find $P(2)$.

---

So far, I have rationalized RHS and rewritten it as $\frac{4}{\sqrt{7} - \sqrt{5}}$. Therefore, $P(x) = \frac{4}{x}$, and hence $P(2) = 2$. But this is not the correct answer (It's $40$).

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: A polynomial must have whole number power of varieables, here it is -1 which is not a whole number.

Comment: @A You only know that the equation $p(x) = 4/x$ has $x = \sqrt{7} + \sqrt{5}$ as a solution, not that $p(x) = 4/x$ for all $x$.

Comment: This is one a bit unfair question because it needs a lot of ingenuity by people who don't know the theory of algebraic field extensions, but is trivial for those who do - and the theory is a staple of Algebra at some University level (often undergraduate), but of course not covered in secondary education. So one could either answer it by watering down the theory for this particular problem (but the solution would look like a trick pulled out of nowhere) - or by presenting the whole theory to you.

Comment: Basically, here is what the trick looks like without any background: let $x=\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{5}$, then $x-\sqrt{7}=\sqrt{5}$ so square both sides: $x^2-2x\sqrt{7}+7=5$, i.e. $2x\sqrt{7}=x^2+2$, then square again to obtain $28x^2=x^4+4x^2+4$ and finally: $x^4-24x^2+4=0$. Divide by $x$: $\frac{4}{x}=-x^3+24x$ where the right-hand side is a polynomial on $x$ and the left side is your old friend $\sqrt{7}-\sqrt{5}=\frac{4}{x}$...

Answer (score 2):

$p(x)=\frac{4}{x}$ is not a polynomial, so it cannot be the answer to this question.

---

Instead, the idea of the solution is based around the minimal polynomial, the smallest degree polynomial $m(x)$ with integer coefficients such that such that $m(\sqrt{7} + \sqrt{5})=0$. Using the idea of conjugates

> (Similar to the idea complex conjugates: $i$ is the part of a complex number that is not real, so the conjugate of $a + bi$ is $a - bi$ - by analogy, $\sqrt{7}$ and $\sqrt{5}$ are the parts of the numbers we are dealing with that are not integers, so the conjugates of $\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{5}$ are $\sqrt{7}-\sqrt{5}$, $-\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{5}$ and $-\sqrt{7}-\sqrt{5}$.)

we know that the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{5}$ is

$$m(x)= (x - \sqrt{7} - \sqrt{5})(x - \sqrt{7} + \sqrt{5})(x + \sqrt{7} - \sqrt{5})(x + \sqrt{7} + \sqrt{5})$$

(similar to how a real polynomial with a complex root also has to have the conjugate as a root)

Expanding it out, we get that $m(x) = x^4 - 24 x^2 + 4$.

---

Now suppose $p(x)$ is an integer polynomial such that $p(\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{5})=2(\sqrt{7}-\sqrt{5})=\frac{4}{\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{5}}$. Then $xp(x)-4$ is an integer polynomial that when applied to $(\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{5})$ gives $0$ so it's divisible by $m(x)$.
In order for $p(x)$ to be as low a degree as possible, we should take $xp(x)-4$ to be an integer multiple of $m(x)$. And we also know that the constant term should be $-4$.

In other words, $xp(x)-4 = -(x^4 - 24 x^2 + 4)$.

---

(The proofs of the various statements here are probably a bit above your level, but the ideas should be accessible if you keep referring back to the analogy with complex conjugates.)

Comment: Even I thought about this problem for a while but couldn't think of an answer within the scope of this exam. Is there no way to solve it using elementary stuff.

Comment: @Hersh They can take all the steps I did using only highschool stuff: it's just multiplying out brackets and rearranging polynomials. The problem is that you can't *know* that those are the right steps to take without the theory of minimal polynomials. I'm kinda hoping that emphasising the analogy to complex conjugates would at least allow students at that level to remember the idea. I'd guess that students who get coached for these contests really practice this sort of technique beforehand.